# Routing on ASP.NET website (not WebForm application and not MVC)

Tags: asp.net, routes, web-config, global-asax

Can I use web.config or Global.asax to do routing in an asp.net website (folder structure)?

Basically I would like

http://www.something.com/agents/10/TheAgentsName

to go to

http://www.something.com/portfolio.aspx?caid=10

The agents name is just for "decoration" in the URL.

I have found several examples but they all apply to MVC or WebForms apps.

When trying to implement Global.asax, it keeps saying that System.Web.Routing does not exist in the namespace. This is what my Global.asax looks like now (it's unable to run)!

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Routing" %>

<script runat="server">

    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        RegisterRoutes(System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes);

    }

    void RegisterRoutes(System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapPageRoute("AgentPortfolioByName", "agents/{id}/{name}", "portfolio.aspx");
    }

    void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
    }

    void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
    }

    void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
    }

    void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
    }

</script>
```

The Global.asax Application_Start is executed fine (I tried to put a break-point). But it just does not understand what System.Web.Routing is. In web.config I have these entries:

```
<compilation debug="true">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/></assemblies>
        </compilation>
```

......

```
<httpModules>
            <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add name="RoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        </httpModules>
```

........

```
<system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
        <modules>
            <remove name="ScriptModule"/>
            <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </modules>
```

Comment: If you're not using WebForms or MVC then what other kind of ASP.NET do you think you're using??

Comment: You know in visual studio you can select "New Project -> ASP.NET WebForms Application" or "New Web Site". This is a Web Site. That means that Global.asax does not have a code-behind for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Global.asax for implement routing. I think you are somehow missing the System.Web.Routing.dll reference in your application. Please make sure you are referencing this one. Also please make sure in Global.asax you are importing  System.Web.Routing namespace. Please go through below link if it will be helpful in understanding the handling Global.asax file in web site application.

http://beyondrelational.com/blogs/niladribiswas/archive/2011/06/09/adding-the-global-asax-cs-file-in-asp-net-web-site.aspx

Please fell free to contact for further discussion.

Thanks,